# Google compute enginer/NodeJS: How to monitor console outputs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, console.log

While in development of my NodeJS based web app I use `console.log()` to display warnings/errors. This was fine until it was in the localhost.
Then I deployed the all in Google compute engine. I start the server using a start up metadata `(sudo node /opt/web-app/bin/www)`.

Now I would cannot figure out how to see my console.log messages. Is there a way to monitor the console outputs or must I use something like Stackdriver?

This is my first time deploying in cloud so appreciate some direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Stackdriver Logging is indeed the way to send your application logs to your Google Cloud project and view them in the Cloud Console: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation

On top of that, you can also log your errors in a specific format that will make Google Stackdriver Error Reporting able to parse them, read more at https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/compute-engine